# Bazel- can a skylark action read a command-line flag (strict_java_deps)

Tags: bazel

I'm working on implementing a feature like `Strict Java Deps` for rules_scala.
I'd really like to have the ability to configure in runtime if this uses `warn` or `error`.

I seem to recall skylark rules can't create and access command-line flags but I don't recall if they can access existing ones?

Main difference is that existing ones are already parsed so maybe they are also passed in some ctx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flag you want (`strict_java_deps`) isn't available through Skylark at the moment.  There's no reason we can't add it, though, filed [#3295](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/3295) to track.

For other flags, the context can access the configuration fragments, which can access some of the parsed command line flags.  I think what you'd want is [ctx.fragments](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/ctx.html#fragments), then use the [fragments](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/fragments.html) to get the [java fragments](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/java.html), and then get the default_javac_flags from that:

```
# rules.bzl
def _impl(ctx):
  print("flags: %s" % ctx.fragments.java.default_javac_flags)
  ...

frag = rule(
    implementation = _impl,
    fragments = ["java"],  # Declare that this rule uses java fragments
)
```

Then:

```
$ bazel build --javacopt="-g:source,lines" :x
WARNING: /home/kchodorow/test/a/tester.bzl:2:3: flags: ["-g:source,lines"].
```

Comment: Thanks! The flag I was looking for is `strict_java_deps`. I think this solution doesn't help me since that fragment is marked as `SkylarkCallable` and `strict_java_deps` is marked as `Option`. Am I correct?

Comment: Oh, yeah, you cannot access that one right now, but there's no reason we couldn't expose it. Filed https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/3295.

Comment: Thanks! Can you update your answer? I'll accept it then

Comment: Edited to add the bug.